# TFS 2013 Tracking Changeset(commits) with GIT

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, alm

With Team Foundation Version Control we have nice ability to visualize changesets. Hierarchy and Timeline view. How can I get same type of information with GIT repository? I can't find anything useful.

**Hierarchy Tracking**
[image: Hierarchy Tracking]

**Timeline view**

[image: Timeline view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure the Visual Studio git client has any visualizations like those built-in, but since the TFS Server Git repo is a standard git repo, you can use any git tooling available.

I know Source Tree has a nice visualization: https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview

Also the git command-line client has:

```
git -log --graph
```

Comment: Dylan is correct stating that there are no visualizations in Visual Studio 2013, but they should be available in the next version, that is Visual Studio 2015.